# Can someone check my DFA?

Tags: computer-science

I need to construct a DFA that accepts strings from the alphabet {a,b} that contain 3 consecutive "ab".This is my try and i am wondering if it's correct?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No.  A $b$ from $q_4$ should take you to $q_0$.

Comment: So apart from that it is correct?Can you think of a string that has 3 consecutive "ab" but will get rejected by my (wrong) dfa?Thanks a lot

Comment: @DrStrange Yup, that's it.  Each even node aside from the last one should kick a $b$ down to $q_0$ and each odd node should kick an $a$ down to $q_1$.  Aside from the one mistake, that's what you have.